# Learning Javascript: comma after member array declaration?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am learning Javascript and came across this code from an example of Knockout.JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    people: [
        new Person("Annabelle", ["Arnie", "Anders", "Apple"]),
        new Person("Bertie", ["Boutros-Boutros", "Brianna", "Barbie", "Bee-bop"]),
        new Person("Charles", ["Cayenne", "Cleopatra"])
        ],
    showRenderTimes: ko.observable(false)
};
```

If I understand this right, 'people' is a member variable containing an array of 'Person' objects. But why is there a comma after the array? Isn't 'showRenderTimes' supposed to be the next member variable declared in the class? Or is it some extension of the 'people' member? Why isn't that comma a semi-colon?

Here's the full listing in case you need it:

```
var Person = function(name, children) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children);

    this.addChild = function() {
        this.children.push("New child");
    }.bind(this);
}

// The view model is an abstract description of the state of the UI, but without any knowledge of the UI technology (HTML)
var viewModel = {
    people: [
        new Person("Annabelle", ["Arnie", "Anders", "Apple"]),
        new Person("Bertie", ["Boutros-Boutros", "Brianna", "Barbie", "Bee-bop"]),
        new Person("Charles", ["Cayenne", "Cleopatra"])
        ],
    showRenderTimes: ko.observable(false)
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Define a "Person" class that tracks its own name and children, and has a method to add a new child
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we have a `viewModel` `Object` which has two fields: `people` and `showRenderTimes`.

So simplifying it looks like this:

```
var viewModel = {people:'something', showRenderTimes:'somethingElse'};
```

You have to separate each field with a coma `,` and that's why it is there.

Another example:

```
var viewModel = {
  people: [],
  showRenderTimes: 'something'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you create objects in JavaScript:

```
var obj = {

    name1:value1,
    name2:value2,
    name3:value3

};
```